# com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException error: How to solve it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, get, gson

I want to get the country details from an external api and using Gson to set the data received from the get request to class Country. The problem is that in the response, the currencies key has value which is between [](please see below) and in some cases there is a space between the currencies name values which causes the following error
*com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 41 path $.currencies[0].name*:

> "currencies":[{"code":"BGN","name":"Bulgarian lev","symbol":"лв"}]

```
@RestController
public class CountryController {
    
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    private static String baseURL = "https://restcountries.com/v2/";
public Object[] getCountryDetails(String countryName){
        Object[] countryDetails = restTemplate.getForObject(baseURL+"name/"+countryName+"?fields=name,alpha2Code,alpha3Code,capital,currencies", Object[].class);
        return countryDetails;
    }
    
    public Country createCountryObject(String countryName) {
        String response = Arrays.asList(getCountryDetails(countryName)).get(0).toString();
        Gson g = new Gson();
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(response.trim()));
        reader.setLenient(true);
        Country country = g.fromJson(reader, Country.class);
        return country;
    }
@GetMapping("/")
    public String getAll(){
        Country country = createCountryObject("bulgaria");
        return country.getName();
    }
}
```

Country.java:

```
package country.neighbours.tour.models;

import java.util.List;

public class Country {
    private String name;
    private String alpha2Code;
    private String alpha3Code;
    private List<String> borders;
    private Object[] currencies;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<String> getBorders() {
        return borders;
    }
    public void setBorders(List<String> borders) {
        this.borders = borders;
    }
    public String getAlpha2Code() {
        return alpha2Code;
    }
    public void setAlpha2Code(String alpha2Code) {
        this.alpha2Code = alpha2Code;
    }
    public String getAlpha3Code() {
        return alpha3Code;
    }
    public void setAlpha3Code(String alpha3Code) {
        this.alpha3Code = alpha3Code;
    }
    public Object[] getCurrencies() {
        return currencies;
    }
    public void setCurrencies(Object[] currencies) {
        this.currencies = currencies;
    }
}
```

**How can I get only the currency code?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are parsing the response twice; once with `restTemplate.getForObject`, then you convert its result to a String (the result of your `toString()` call is most likely **not JSON**) and then you try to parse it a second time with Gson.

In case you only want to use Gson, you can use a [`TypeToken`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) in the `fromJson` call to parse the response JSON array:

```java
List<Country> countries = gson.fromJson(..., new TypeToken<List<Country>>() {}.getType());
```

Maybe someone more familiar with Spring can also explain how to use only `RestTemplate.getForObject` for this instead of Gson.